# Decomposing a probit/logit regression

Tags: logistic, econometrics, residuals, probit, decomposition

In an econometric work, I want to assess the causal effect of *n* variables on a binary character variable *y*, while I highly suspect that the relation between one of these regressors, say *x* (which is numerical), and *y*, is dependent on the value of *x*. Thus, I aim at using a non-parametric (local) logistic regression.

In order to avoid the curse of dimensionality, and because a classical logistic regression seems appropriate for the relation between the *n-1* other variables and *y*, it would really help me to get answers to the following question:

**Is their a way to do a classical logistic regression involving the *n-1* first regressors, then to do the non parametric regression involving simply *x*, and then to link those two regressions to have the causal effect of each variable ?**

In a linear model, I would run the first regression between *y* and the *n-1* regressors, then run a non-parametric regression of the residual on *x*, but I do not think it is possible to do it in a logistic framework.

Thanks a lot,

PB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are discussions / doubts about whether this approach is useful in general, see e.g. https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2656.2002.00618.x

Just from the technical side though (dealing with the logistic residuals), the quantile residuals calculated by the DHARMa package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html should allow you to do what you describe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !